# What does this mean in wordpress? Easy question

Tags: php, theme-development, themes

Im digging wordpress and started to look into templates to be specific blank themes/frameworks for making custom themes. I found "HTML5Blank" and was going through source code and found something i do not understand.

```
<h1 class="htittle"><?php _e( 'News', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>
```

What is the part **'html5blank'** doing? Its repeating everywhere. Its not in the comments so its got to be some part of wordpress codex but i dont know even what to google. More examples :

```
<h1><?php _e( 'About ', 'html5blank' ); echo get_the_author() ; ?></h1>
```

again there is... ***, 'html5blank' )*** . Why is that here? Even more examples

```
<span class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></span>
```

Here its repeating more times, i cant figure it out.

Then i went through the sourc of another blank framework called "Bones". Again same thing

```
<p><?php _e( 'This is the error message in the archive.php template.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
```

**,'bonestheme'** ?? what is this doing?

```
<h1><?php _e( 'Oops, Post Not Found!', 'bonestheme' ); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Have you even looked at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e)?

Comment: I examined the codex but obviously superficial, but thanks for the link, I knew it was an easy question and I did not know how to search the codex for that.

Comment: You can find the function by searching for `wp [function name]` in for example google.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [text domain](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), used for translation. When you run something like this:

```
<?php _e( 'Hello World', 'html5blank' ) ?>
```

...WordPress will attempt to find the translated string in the loaded MO file for HTML5 Blank:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'html5blank', 'path/to/language.mo' );
```

Comment: What will happen if i delete that ? Is this required?

Comment: If you want to change the text just replace the whole snippet with a hardcoded value.